# "Most" vs. "most of"

Tags: phrases, word-usage, articles, determiners, partitives

> During **most of history**, humans were too busy to think about thought.

Why is "most of history" correct in the above sentence?

I could understand the difference between "Most of the people" and "Most people".

Problem is why "Most of history" is correct.

Comment: @Kris No longer. Now [ell.SE](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @StoneyB Oh right. Thanks. I'm deleting the comment.

Comment: Agreed, it seemed very simple, but it turns up an interesting feature of the senses of *history*.

Answer (score 2):

The sense of *history* used here identifies a particular period. Now just what that period is may be unclear or may differ between similar uses (in particular, whether prehistory—the period before writing was invented and hence written records available—is included or not will differ between uses).

But despite this ambiguity, it still refers to one particular thing. While we do not capitalise it, it's more a proper noun in this sense than it is a common noun, for just as *Jon* identifies one person (in a given use), *history* in this use identifies one period, albeit the period that covers everything.

Other uses of *history* are countable or mass uses:

To take StoneyB's examples:

> Most history is lies.

This uses *history* as a mass noun to cover all that is said about the past. Hence *most* is used to identify the greater part of that mass, that is to say the greater part all that is said about the past.

> Most histories are boring.

This uses *history* as a countable noun, to refer to a particular account. (Or rather in the plural, to refer to particular accounts). Here *most* identifies a certain number of this plural amount.

> During most of history, humans were too busy to think about thought.

This uses *history* as a proper noun, to refer to a particular period in time. We could interpret it either as since writing began, or since humans began (from context we clearly don't care about earlier than that), but however we interpret it, it's talking about **one** individual, particular period.

It uses *most of* to identify the larger part of that particular period.

In comparison, *water*:

> Most waters are healthy.

Uses *water* as a countable noun, in the plural (as can be done to differentiate water from different sources), and applies *most* to that plural number.

> Most water is healthy.

Uses *water* as a mass noun, and applies *most* to that mass.

Now, we don't have a sense of *water* on its own that applies to one individual. We can though use "the water" to apply to a particular bit of water.

> Most of the water is healthy.

Again, because we're dealing with an individual case, we use *most of* rather than *most*

Generally we use "most…" or "most of the…". The first refers to the majority of all that the noun phrase refers to "most butterflies are pretty". The second refers to a particular identified set of what the noun phrase refers to "most of the butterflies I've seen were pretty".

The difference is unspecific group vs. specific group.

Because *history* in the sense of the question is already specific, without a definite article, we're essentially using the "most of the…" form, but without the *the*.

Likewise, with proper nouns, we only use *the* if *the* is normally part of that proper noun; "Most of Europe" and "Most of the Rolling Stones" differ because we don't say "the Europe" but we do say "the Rolling Stones".

Comment: But there's another problem here, and I think it's what OP is asking about: why not *✲During most history*? *Most history is lies* and *most histories are boring* are OK. *Most American culture is superficial* is OK. It parallels another 'extent' word: *road*.  *✲Most road between here and Duluth is Interstate*. I thought it had to do with mass/collective/count noun senses, but that doesn't work.

Comment: @StoneyB I got it, and you nearly did too I think. You forgot that there's another alternative to mass, collective and count; there's individuals as per proper nouns.

Comment: Bingo. You da man. ... and you don't capitalize it because otherwise people might mistake you for Hegel.

Comment: @StoneyB it would almost justify capitalising *History* when used in such a sense, though that could lead to a return of the capitalisation of "significant" nouns: perhaps the one feature of the history of the language I have no soft spot for and my gladness that it is not still with us is completely unalloyed.

Comment: mmm I use a lot of ironic capitals. 18th-century commas are my black beast.

Comment: @StoneyB *The Title Format : in which we encounter Titles and Subtitles of great Length that continue on until they have provided Abﬅract, Preface, Dedication and oft as not Concluſion, being of such Extent that we ſhould ſuſpect the Editor were brib'd by the Printer to increaſe his Takings* are a continual amusement to me, but whereas I find catchwords and other features of printing of the time to justify their existence, and I miss the beauty of some of the ligatures common to the age (`ct` especially), I do find such capitals never cease to grate when I'm actually trying to read such texts.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'Most of' is gramatically correct if you are including "the". Otherwise you'd be saying 'Most people', etc. which is the same.

I'd also say that using 'Most of' implies that there is a perceived population, a finite number of people being referred to. For instance
Most people (e.g. a generalization) like chocolate.
vs.
Most of the people (e.g. 'in this house') like chocolate.

Comment: What about mass nouns? They surely behave differently to countable nouns.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "most of" when you want to point at something. you can not say "most my books" but you can say "most of my books". or you can't say "most history" so the right form is " most of history".

Answer (score 0):

Interesting! So Here is what I think, let me know of constructive thoughts:

look at this syntax

> most of *

Where the * represents a sense of quantity. So suggesting a part/portion (of considerable quantity) of the things that follow ahead.
where as the syntax:

```
most *
```

does not suggest cutting out a portion, rather generalizes things. eg:
most movies I went to.....

What do you guys think?

Comment: You're very close. The distinction here is between a [mass noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun) like *water* or *furniture* and a [collective noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun) like *team* or *people*.

Comment: gotchya. Thanks.
so, does it close the topic as an answer?

Comment: I thought it did, but now I find it doesn't work