# Most or Most of

Tags: grammar, word-usage, determiners, partitives

Should we say :
Most of the american women loved Michael Jackson
or
Most american women loved Michael Jackson

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Most" vs. "most of"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103047/most-vs-most-of). [Another possible duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205598/quantifiers-most-vs-most-of)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is slightly different than the question linked to by JJJ, because in this case, either phrase could be correct (depending on intended meaning), whereas in that other question only one of the possible phrases was correct.

It would be correct to use "most of the American women" as part of a comparison. The phrase emphasizes the fact that the attitudes of one group (American women) were different than the attitudes of some other group who held another view (for example, French women who dislike Michael Jackson). However, this wouldn't be the right phrase to use in a more general situation where you are not comparing different groups of people's opinions on something.

The phrase "most American women" could also be used as part of a comparison, but unlike "most of the American women," it could be used as part of a more general statement.

"American" should be capitalized.